# Inserting a character in a string when there isn't a match in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I am trying to figure out a way to insert a character into a string if that character doesn't match.

Let's say I have these two strings:

```
s1: CGGGTATCCAA
s2: CCCTAGGTCCCA
```

It should output this:

```
s1: C----GGGTATCC-AA
s2: CCCTAGG-T--CCCA-
```

The algorithm is as follows:

```
if(lengthOfs1 > lengthOfs2)
    if character mismatch
       put a dash on s2
    else
       put the original character
else if(lengthOfs1 <= lengthOfs2)
    if character mistmatch
       put a dash on s1
    else
       put the original character
```

I've tried to accomplish this by having the two original strings, and looping through a for loop until I hit '\0' in a string. Then I do the compares, and finally use something like:

```
strncpy(&s1_final_string[i + 1], &s1[i], 1) // if they are equal
strncpy(&s1_final_string[i], "-", 1); // if I need to put a dash
```

Is there a simple way to approach this situation and copy over a '-' character if we have a mismatch?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question? Your algorithm seems basically fine.  If you allocate s1_final_string and s2_final_string to be strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) in size, then all you need to do is keep track of your s1_index, s2_index, s1_final_index and s2_final_index while you iteratively implement your algorithm.  Also, there's no need to use strncpy instead of just setting the character directly.  For example, s1_final_string[s1_final_index++] = s1_string[s1_index++];

Comment: Having thought about, I think this problem is considerably harder than you think it is.  I think what you are **ACTUALLY** after is a difference algorithm that finds a minimum difference (or maximal match) between the two strings and then fills in the mismatched positions with dashes.  Something like the algorithm that powers the diff program, but goes character by character rather than line by line.

Comment: You could do something simpler like a greedy algorithm.  For example, at each mismatch point search ahead for the next matching character in both strings and only add dashes to whichever string would result in less dashes for that mismatch.  That might give you something like your desired output on that input, but might give sub-optimal results under other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a greedy difference algorithm that matches your input and output.  Please note that this algorithm does not find a minimal mismatch between any two strings.  Instead, at each mismatch point it scans ahead in both strings to find the next matching points and uses whichever one is closer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int greedy_diff_str(const char *s1, const char *s2, char **s1_final_ptr, char **s2_final_ptr)
{
  size_t s1_len = strlen(s1);
  size_t s2_len = strlen(s2);
  size_t s1_index = 0, s2_index = 0, final_index = 0;
  char  *s1_final, *s2_final;

  if (NULL == (s1_final = *s1_final_ptr = (char*) calloc(s1_len + s2_len + 1, 1)))
  {
    *s2_final_ptr = NULL;
    return -1;
  }

  if (NULL == (s2_final = *s2_final_ptr = (char*) calloc(s1_len + s2_len + 1, 1)))
  {
    free(s1_final);
    *s1_final_ptr = NULL;
    return -1;
  }

  while ('\0' != s1[s1_index] && '\0' != s2[s2_index])
  {
    if (s1[s1_index] == s2[s2_index])
    {
      s1_final[final_index]   = s1[s1_index++];
      s2_final[final_index++] = s2[s2_index++];
      //printf("s1: '%s'\ns2: '%s'\n", s1_final, s2_final);
    }
    else
    {
      size_t s1_dashes, s2_dashes, i;

      /* count how many dashes we'd have to add to s1 to reach next match point with s2 */

      for (i = s2_index + 1; '\0' != s2[i] && s1[s1_index] != s2[i]; ++i);
      s1_dashes = i - s2_index;

      /* count how many dashes we'd have to add to s2 to reach next match point with s1 */

      for (i = s1_index + 1; '\0' != s1[i] && s2[s2_index] != s1[i]; ++i);
      s2_dashes = i - s1_index;

      //printf("mismatch at s1[%lu] = '%c'; s2[%lu] = '%c'; s1_dashes = %lu; s2_dashes = %lu\n", s1_index, s1[s1_index], s2_index, s2[s2_index], s1_dashes, s2_dashes); 

      /* pick whichever path results in less dashes; break ties by adding dashes to string from which we've consumed more */

      if (s1_dashes < s2_dashes || (s1_dashes == s2_dashes && s1_index >= s2_index))
      {
        while (s1_dashes--)
        {
          s1_final[final_index]   = '-';
          s2_final[final_index++] = s2[s2_index++];
        }        
      }
      else
      {
        while (s2_dashes--)
        {
          s1_final[final_index]   = s1[s1_index++];
          s2_final[final_index++] = '-';
        }
      }

      //printf("s1: '%s'\ns2: '%s'\n", s1_final, s2_final);
    }
  }

  for (; '\0' != s1[s1_index]; ++s1_index, ++final_index)
  {
    s1_final[final_index] = s1[s1_index];
    s2_final[final_index] = '-';
    //printf("s1: '%s'\ns2: '%s'\n", s1_final, s2_final);
  }

  for (; '\0' != s2[s2_index]; ++s2_index, ++final_index)
  {
    s1_final[final_index] = '-';
    s2_final[final_index] = s2[s2_index];
    //printf("s1: '%s'\ns2: '%s'\n", s1_final, s2_final);
  }

  s1_final[final_index] = '\0';
  s2_final[final_index] = '\0';

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  char s1[] = "CGGGTATCCAA", s2[] = "CCCTAGGTCCCA", *s1_fin, *s2_fin;

  printf("Input:\n");
  printf("s1: '%s'\n", s1);
  printf("s2: '%s'\n", s2);

  greedy_diff_str(s1, s2, &s1_fin, &s2_fin);

  printf("Output:\n");
  printf("s1: '%s'\n", s1_fin);
  printf("s2: '%s'\n", s2_fin);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of a run:

```
john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ ./a.out
Input:
s1: 'CGGGTATCCAA'
s2: 'CCCTAGGTCCCA'
Output:
s1: 'C----GGGTATCC-AA'
s2: 'CCCTAGG-T--CCCA-'
```